# location-based Augmented Reality Framework (Android, iOS) with 3D POIs?

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, augmented-reality, location-based

I search a location-based Augmented Reality Framework with 3D POIs for Android, iOS or most suitable for both?

It should not be something like Wikitude or Layer, because the user must always download the app from Wikitude or Layer to use my own app. Right?

I would like to integrate it into my own app. I've found [Mixare](http://www.mixare.org/), but yet it seems this uses no 3D POIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only Android: In [DroidAR](http://code.google.com/p/droidar/) it seems to be easily add prefabricated 3-D POIs.

Comment: Hi is there any doc / tutorial on adding onclick events to POIs added . I am trying droidAR . Thanks a lot for youyr help

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for such a thing as well.  I just found http://www.3dar.us/ which seems like a good place to start for iOS.  It isn't open source, which is a bummer.

Edit:

I have tried out Mixare, and I am really impressed by it.  I have compiled it for Android.  The only part that gave me a hard time was making sure the project was using the Google API v10, and that I had it installed.

Mixare does easily support Points of interest (POI)  Check out their [wikipage](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/DisplayYourOwnData) for more about it, basically you just feed it JSON.  I am personally going use CouchDB with GeoCouch to serve up data, with free hosting provided by [iriscouch](http://www.iriscouch.com/)

The JSON should look like the following:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "num_results": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "2827",
            "lat": "46.43893",
            "lng": "11.21706",
            "elevation": "1737",
            "title": "Penegal",
            "distance": "9.756",
            "has_detail_page": "1",
            "webpage": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suedtirolerland.it%2Fapi%2Fmap%2FgetMarkerTplM%2F%3Fmarker_id%3D2827%26project_id%3D15%26lang_id%3D9"
        }
    ]
}
```

The most wonderful thing is that it is GPLed!

Comment: [android-augment-reality-framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/) based on Mixare. Perhaps it is also interesting for you ;).

Comment: I will check it out more deeply, after digging into the Mixare source it provides lots of ways to get your own data in as well.  Can you make a compelling argument for using android-augment-reality-framework ?

Comment: I don't know! It is perhaps limited to the essential and so clearly arranged?

Answer (score 1):

There is a code contribution to mixare that implements an OpenGL horizon plane. It's available here:
https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/mixare/commit/0a8a7e070ef076239e0cb39606f3ac85faa324fe

It's only a start since it's not linked to the data sources, but the basics should be there
Next week we are going to have an hackathon ( http://www.mixare.org/2011/11/its-almost-hackathon-time-are-you-ready/ ) and while I can't promise anything, openGL is definitely on the to-do list :-)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Layar Player](http://www.layar.com/player/). "The Layar Player is a tool that enables anyone to embed augmented reality layers directly into their very own application". "Currently the Layar Player is for iPhone only, but an Android version will be available in Q4 later this year". That sounds very good! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Appunta AR](https://code.google.com/p/appunta/) works like a charm. Android Only