# Augmented Reality and Clusters

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am working on Augmented Reality project. I am using http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/ which is a modification of mixare sdk. Now I need to perform clusters (Display POIs in group if they are more than 5). I am able to detect the collision between overlays. But not able to form the clusters. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/samples-tutorials/architect-tutorial-3-geo-ar-poi/

[location-based Augmented Reality Framework (Android, iOS) with 3D POIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673490/location-based-augmented-reality-framework-android-ios-with-3d-pois)

Note:Check these links

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have already implemented lot of things using above mentioned framework. Choosing different sdk will be tough for me at this stage. Any idea using the same framework ?